# IE9 bug? Opening a PDF bring a whitescreen on any following actions

Tags: pdf, iframe, internet-explorer-9, acrobat

Using IE9 (not 64bit) when we open a page containing an PDF file within an iframe, any other action taken will screw our UI (complete whitescreen).

Here an example.

Use this link: http://unik.caij.qc.ca/default.aspx?&unikid=70131

As soon as you hit the hyperlink `<-Retour à la liste des résultats` you'll see a blank screen but the DOM elements seems to be there.

Any idea what could be wrong, our code, IE9, the PDF plug in? Is it a rendering problem??

This happend only with IE9.

I did all the windows update and adobe reader X update.

Comment: Note: This happens even without the Acrobat plugin. Fun fact: It seems to work when the Developer Tools are open.

Comment: yeah true. It works most of the time but we found a few other scenario where it's not working. Anyway, we cannot tell our user to open the developper tool to avoid the bug. :-)